# how to append two tables with different columns in aws athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want help in writing a query which appends two tables with some similar columns and other columns too.
For example if I have 2 tables,

**Table 1:**

```
   name    age    place
    n1      a1       p1
    n2      a2       p2
    n3      a3       p3
```

**Table 2:**

```
   name    place   country
    n4       p4      c4
    n5       p5      c5
    n6       p6      c6
```

I want to append these two tables to get

**Table 3:**

```
  name    age   place   country
    n1      a1     p1       NULL   
    n2      a2     p2       NULL
    n3      a3     p3       NULL
    n4      NULL   p4       c4     
    n5      NULL   p5       c5
    n6      NULL   p6       c6
```

Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: pls *format your code* appropriately

Comment: I don't think this post was worth two downvotes due to not formatting.  The way I look at the formatting is free points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [UNION](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) query with placeholders for missing columns on each table:

```
SELECT name, age, place, null AS country FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT name, null AS age, place, country FROM table2
ORDER BY name;
```

Notice that I have created two columns so that each result set has the same set of columns.